# How to return a subscription in angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

How do you return a subscription in Angular that is being called on an injectable?

So what I did at first that took me an hour to figure out is this:

```
 returnURLNotes(): Observable<any> {
    return this.store.select(selectDentureDesignNotes).subscribe((notes) => {
      if (
        notes &&
        notes[this._CANVAS_NAME] &&
        notes[this._CANVAS_NAME].length > 0
      ) {
        return notes[this._CANVAS_NAME];
      }
    });
  }
```

See the first return? I just returned the `store.selector` and this approach doesn't work. because the inner return won't be available as a return value of `returnURLs` method.

So here's my solution. It's working but I don't know if this is the right way.

```
returnURLNotes(): any {
    let URLs = {};
    const URLNotes$ = this.store.select(selectDentureDesignNotes);
    URLNotes$.subscribe((notes) => {
      if (
        notes &&
        notes[this._CANVAS_NAME] &&
        notes[this._CANVAS_NAME].length > 0
      ) {
        URLs = notes[this._CANVAS_NAME];
      }
    });

    return URLs;
  }
```

But I don't feel like that this is the right way because of JS single-threaded or "asynchronousity."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first example shows you are trying to return an observable. This is how you would do that using rxjs using what you have provided. This utilizes rxjs [filter](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/filter.html) and [map](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/map.html). You probably dont want to return the subscription directly, but rather subscribe to the observable your function is returning.

```js
returnURLNotes(): Observable <any> {
    return this.store.select(selectDentureDesignNotes).pipe(
        filter(notes => notes &&
            notes[this._CANVAS_NAME] &&
            notes[this._CANVAS_NAME].length > 0),
        map(notes => notes[this._CANVAS_NAME])
    );
}
```

Comment: so this will return the values or I still have to subscribe on the method that is using this?

Comment: it will return an observable of the values, so you would do something like  returnURLNotes().subscribe(...);